# Oracle VM Virtualbox requirements?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, requirements

I'm new to this site. I have a question about Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Having looked through the documentation I can't find the minimum requirements, would anyone happen to know what it requires?

I'm trying to use my windows 7 work PC and my boss wants to know if we need more RAM.

Comment: How much RAM do you want to give your virtual machine? VMVB adds little overhead to that.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [End user documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/End-user_documentation):

> **Memory.**
>
> Depending on what guest operating systems you want to run, you will need at least 512 MB of RAM (but probably more, and the more the better). Basically, you will need whatever your host operating system needs to run comfortably, plus the amount that the guest operating system needs. So, if you want to run Windows XP on Windows XP, you probably won't enjoy the experience much with less than 1 GB of RAM. If you want to try out Windows Vista in a guest, it will refuse to install if it is given less than 512 MB RAM, so you'll need that for the guest alone, plus the memory your operating system normally needs.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I couldn't find this section. :D